# How to change page getting response from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have 4 files:

HTML form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php base_url(); ?>ajax/request.js"></script>
    <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>CRAWLER</h1>
<textarea cols="60" rows="5" id="wartosc"></textarea>
<br>
<button>Send</button> 
</body>
</html>
```

JS file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        var zmienna = $('#wartosc').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: window.location+"/curl/",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                wartosc: zmienna
            },
            success: function (odp) {
                $('#wynik').html(odp);
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Codeigniter curl controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Curl extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['wartosc'])) {
            $adresy = explode("\n", $_POST['wartosc']);
            foreach ($adresy as $lista_adresow) {
                $this->get_data($lista_adresow);
            }
        }
    }
    function get_data($adres)
    {
        $url = $adres;
        $c = curl_init();
        $opcje = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE
        );
        curl_setopt_array($c, $opcje);
        curl_exec($c);
        $info = curl_getinfo($c);
        $tablica = array() + $info;
        if ($info['redirect_url'] != NULL) {
            $this->get_data($info['redirect_url']);
        }
        return $tablica;
    }
}
```

And Codeigniter Test controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
         $data['val_from_ajax']=//need value from curl controller here
         $this->load->view('view',$data);
    }
}
```

I use ajax to send value from form to curl controller and i result ($tablica) back to HTML form, but i need  this array in Test controller.

Problem:
How i can change jquery.ajax() function to return request not to form file,only to test controller?
Its hard for me to explain what i need to do, sorry for this

Thanks

Comment: I don't follow the question. What is "ajax response destination"? Do you mean that you want people hitting this url in a browser to get HTML, but people hitting it through AJAX to get just data, like JSON?

Comment: You are missing the "return false" in your ajax script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing please correct me if I am wrong. If you have created Curl controller just for executing curl commands, then you can also do those thing in Test controller. Something like

```
class Test extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['wartosc']))
        {
            $adresy = explode("\n", $_POST['wartosc']);
            $needed_value = $this->get_data($adresy);
        }

        $data['val_from_ajax']= $needed_value;//need value from curl controller here
        $this->load->view('view',$data);
    }

    function get_data($adres)
        {
            foreach ($adres as $lista_adresow)
            {
                $url = $lista_adresow;
                $c = curl_init();
                $opcje = array(
                    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE
                );
                curl_setopt_array($c, $opcje);
                curl_exec($c);
                $info = curl_getinfo($c);
                $tablica = array() + $info;
                if ($info['redirect_url'] != NULL) {
                    $this->get_data($info['redirect_url']);
                }
            }
            return $tablica;
        }
}
```

The above code is roughly done. There may be corrections also you may need to change the ajax call appropriately. Let us know if it works

Comment: Works but with problems, $tablica array returned from get_data function have all information and when I var_dump($needed_value) get only part of data returned array $tablica and dont know why